# Bitnami Permissions php.ini

Tags: bitnami

I am trying the modify a php.ini file in a bitnami moodle deployment, as user 'bitnami' but for some reason my permissions are denied through sftp.

I have never used the console before, so can someone please provide some step by step instructions to modify these files or permissions.

Answer (score 4):

When you launched a Bitnami Moodle Cloud Image, the permissions set by default for the file `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini` are 0644 with `user: bitnami group: root`. Therefore, if you are connecting via SSH to your server using the user 'bitnami' you must be able to edit the file.

On the other hand, the permissions set by default to the folder `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/` are 0755 with `user: root group: root`. Therefore, to create a new file on that folder you must have root permissions. That's the reason why you can't upload a new file via SFTP to that folder with user 'bitnami'.

More information at:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/#how-to-connect-to-the-server-through-ssh
https://docs.bitnami.com/general/faq/#how-to-upload-files-to-the-server-with-sftp